# Styled components Typescript interface not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, styled-components

I'm adding `styled-components` to react typescript projects. Everything look fine just until I declare `interface` and add to styled component I created.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Flex = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: ${props => props.direction};
`;
```

The one above works fine.

Later, I add interface to this one like this.

```
interface FlexProps {
    direction?: 'row' | 'column';
}

const Flex = styled.div<FlexProps>`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: ${props => props.direction};
`;
```

My page is broken with this error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: FlexProps is not defined` from browser console.

This is the version of my package.

```
"styled-components": "^4.3.2",
"@types/styled-components": "^4.1.18",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
"babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.6",
"typescript": "~3.2.1",
```

Comment: What TypeScript version are you using? It seems that this syntax is incorrect until 2.9.

Comment: Do you get this error in the browser? Usually you only get JS errors in the browser, TS errors in the compiler output. Does your file have a TS or TSX ending?

Comment: I updated my question add more detail there.
here is Ts version `"typescript": "~3.2.1",`
And the error I got is come from browser console.

Comment: If it comes from the browser console, it most likely means that this file isn't getting compiled.

Comment: I'm confusing why because in the project we have both JS and TS there. And it is working fine. Even React component written in TS still work fine. only styled components doesn't work.

Comment: Running into this as well. Though I optimistically updated everything to latest :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the interface on the div and put it in your arrow function instead.

Like this

```
const Flex = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: ${(props: FlexProps) => props.direction};
`;
```

Comment: that's an old school pattern I think.
Have a look their document: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props